# Calibration curve in spss

Tags: spss, model, roc, calibration

I couldn't find any tutorials on this on youtube or otherwise. I am validating a clinical prediction model and I have a set of predicted outcomes and the real outcome. I have built a ROC curve but I would like to build a calibration curve between the expected % and observed %. What are the steps I need to follow? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does an ROC curve have to do with it?

Comment: In validating the model, I need the ROC curve for its discriminatory ability and the calibration curve to measure its calibration.

Comment: The calibration curve is a great approach.  The ROC curve is not relevant here, only the ROC area is, just because it happens to equal the concordance probability (c-index) which is a measure of pure discrimination (proportional to Wilcoxon statistic).

Answer (score 1):

In order to make calibration plot, you will have to do following steps yourself.
There is no automatic process.
    1. You should have dependent/outcome variable and predictions.
    2. Do visual binning of predictions. Transform --> Visual binning
    3. Aggregate mean of outcome variable based on binned variable. Data --> Aggregate
    4. Draw a graph using binned var on X and density on Y.
    5. To Draw a line, go to Analyze --> regression --> Curve Estimation
(In step#3, I have assumed that your outcome variable is 0 or 1, and hence in this case mean will be the probability of event happening in that bin).

Full syntax and commands follow.

**Creating binned variable:**
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
* Visual Binning.
*PRE_2.
RECODE  PRE_2 (MISSING=COPY) (LO THRU 0.000975873501824482=1) (LO THRU 0.00141701125412073=2) (LO 
    THRU 0.00179052964935964=3) (LO THRU 0.00220329549806634=4) (LO THRU 0.00266698550653581=5) (LO 
    THRU 0.00314263285616621=6) (LO THRU 0.00364267374421248=7) (LO THRU 0.00422690221=8) (LO THRU 
    0.00488431785475026=9) (LO THRU 0.00571507327812430=10) (LO THRU 0.00727421434905541=11) (LO THRU 
    HI=12) (ELSE=SYSMIS) INTO Binned_pred2.
VARIABLE LABELS  Binned_pred2 'Predicted probability (Binned)'.
FORMATS  Binned_pred2 (F5.0).
VALUE LABELS  Binned_pred2 1 '' 2 '' 3 '' 4 '' 5 '' 6 '' 7 '' 8 '' 9 '' 10 '' 11 '' 12 ''.
VARIABLE LEVEL  Binned_pred2 (ORDINAL).

EXECUTE.



**Calculating Density of event:**

AGGREGATE

  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=Binned_pred2
  /outcome_SDH_mean_1=MEAN(outcome_SDH).

**Draw a graph:**

Copy these two newly created Vars to a new data set and then find duplicate and eliminate them.
Fit a line. Using curve fit. Analyze --> regression --> curve fit
* Curve Estimation.
TSET NEWVAR=NONE.
CURVEFIT
  /VARIABLES=Binned_pred2 WITH Density_outcome_SDH
  /CONSTANT
  /MODEL=LINEAR LOGARITHMIC INVERSE QUADRATIC CUBIC COMPOUND POWER S GROWTH EXPONENTIAL
  /PRINT ANOVA
  /PLOT FIT.

Hope it helps.
Thanks!

Comment: please improve the formmating of the question